# Printing square boxes in crystal report

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, crystal-reports-2008

Please guide me to print boxes like this in crystal report[Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iIl8.png).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the data you're displaying. If you want just boxes of consecutive numbers, maybe you can just create a bunch of text-boxes with solid borders and type the numbers in them. Crystal reports may not be the best tool for that.

If you want to display data in columns and rows, that would be a [Cross-tab report](https://www.google.com/search?q=crystal%20reports%20crosstab).